# Using $slice in Spring MongoDB Repository with @Query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, jhipster

I am using Spring Boot with MongoDB. In this project, I have the domain class ControlVariable, which has an array attribute named ControlVarEntries. I have been trying to use the operator $slice to get only the last five controlVarEntries of all controlVars when retrieving them in my own findAll method. This query works when tried in my Mongo client:

```
db.getCollection('controlVariable').find( {}, { controlVarEntries: { $slice: -5 } } )
```

However, I tried a similar approach in my Spring Boot project with the @Query annotation and I could not retrieve the same results. This, for instance, returns all the entries:

```
@Repository
public interface ControlVariableRepository extends MongoRepository<ControlVariable, String> {

    @Query("{ controlVarEntries: { $slice: ?0 } }")
    Page<ControlVariable> findAllLimitedNumberOfEntriesQuery(Pageable pageable, Integer numberOfEntries);

}
```

I would like to know if my query is wrong or if I am not using the proper syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: you should use `$slice: ?1` I believe

Comment: It is not working either, unfortunately.

I should also say that I tried without using any params:

@Query("{}, { controlVarEntries: { $slice: 5 } }")

But it was wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to identify the projection document in the @Query annotation.

Try

```
@Query(value="{}", fields = "{'controlVarEntries': { '$slice': ?0 } }")
Page<ControlVariable> findAllLimitedNumberOfEntriesQuery(Pageable pageable, Integer numberOfEntries);
```